# How to redesign an instance where common functionality (in a parent class) warrants returning instances of the children?

Tags: python, selenium, design-patterns

As per the title, I know this is inherently terrible design, as a parent should know nothing about its children. However, I am in the scenario where

1. All children have reusable behaviour that could be derived from the parent class,
2. Those reusable methods that *all* subclasses need, warrant returning instances of the current sub classes!

I need all child classes to have the repeatable behaviour but also have the parent class capable of returning instances of the children, this will need a complete refactor, but how do I design it properly?

I have tried using composition instead here, the only problem being that all classes will have to have to declare an explicit public API for using the common functionality and each and every subclass in the future will need to declare it.

```
class BasePage(object):
    # Some Very Common Behaviour goes here.
    # Nothing product specific, just selenium specific 

class ProductBasePage(BasePage):
    # Reusable behaviour here for the product
    # Some of this behaviour in the parent does web-app navigation
    # which merits (quite rightly) to return instances of children
    # pages, for example (CustomersPage, DashboardPage, ProductsPage)
    # but this is clearly flawed and inheritance is not the answer?
    # but how do I keep the functionality that all subclasses need
    # without then declaring it explicitly in every one of them?

class CustomersPage(ProductBasePage):
    # Customer specific behaviour
    # Should have access the common functionality implicitly from the parent
```

Customer Page and all other pages which extend the product page should have the ability to use a lot of common functionality that all of the subclasses of ProductBasePage should have, without having each and every subclass to define that behaviour explicitly. The re-usable methods however, return instances of ProductBasePages sub classes as their actions warrant this behaviour.

So how do I achieve this? I think Inheritance is not the answer here, but then how do I get reusability of the common functionality without declaring it explicitly in every class?

The solution to this problem should avoid circular Python import dependencies as well.

Comment: I'm afraid your question - as currently formulated - is a bit too broad get a proper answer. Could you edit your code snippet to include a couple practical examples of common behaviours / subclasses instanciation patterns (even if dummy, that's not the point) that demonstrate your problem ?

Comment: In the meantime, you may want to have a look at the factory / factory method patterns and eventually the vistor pattern (not sure this one makes sense here though).

Answer (score -1):

Just put those reusable methods into a separated class, and make them `static`. Then the subclasses can call those methods implicitly.

If you don't want to use static methods, go with plain functions.

Comment: Python is not Java. If all you have in class a is a bunch of staticmethods, then chances are you just want a module with plain functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's implementation detail, but the same idea applies.